# set expiry date for an account in the future has problem

Tags: centos, passwd

The output of `passwd -S` command shows a date which is quite confusing. Please see the following commands

```
root@cluster:~# passwd  -S 9240305
9240305 LK 1970-01-01 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
root@cluster:~#
root@cluster:~# passwd -u 9240305
Unlocking password for user 9240305.
passwd: Success
root@cluster:~# passwd  -S 9240305
9240305 PS 1970-01-01 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
root@cluster:~# date
Sun Jul  3 22:18:22 IRDT 2016
root@cluster:~# usermod --lock --expiredate 2016-09-01 9240305
root@cluster:~# passwd  -S 9240305
9240305 LK 1970-01-01 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
```

The first command shows an account is locked. The date is 1970 which is vague for me. The second command enables the account but again we see (Third command) that the date is 1970. The fifth command set an expire date and locks the account. I expect that the account will be locked in 2016-09-01. Still the sixth command shows 1970.

What does that mean?

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your date. The date 1970 is not a part from UTC format: `The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970. There is a problem with this definition, in that UTC did not exist in its current form until 1972; this issue is discussed below. For brevity, the remainder of this section uses ISO 8601 date format, in which the Unix epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.`

 I think that using the "chage" command is more useful. Example: 
`chage -d 30 username`. Where -d sets the days when to expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date returned by `passwd -S` is the time the password was last changed, not the date it is due to expire.   1/1/1970 is the "unix epoch" - ie time zero.

If you look at `/etc/shadow` you'll see the third field is a number; this is the number of days past the epoch that the password was set.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that password and account expirations are two different things.

Comment: Yes, good point.  `man 5 shadow` explains the fields and the difference between passwd/account expiration pretty well.

Comment: Excuse me, but still I cannot understand why the account has been quickly locked after the expire date (I set the expire and lock for the next two months). I am telling to expire and lock the account on September 2016. Isn't that? How linux interpret that command?

Comment: You added `--lock` which _immediately_ locks the account.